# My Ubuntu 10.10 is not supported. How do I totally get rid of 10.10 and go to a new version?

Tags: lubuntu

I have Ubuntu 10.10. Commands aren't working. I can't install anything. Ubuntu Software Center won't load. And other programs won't either. How do I get the newest version of Ubuntu and totally get rid of the Ubuntu 10.10? Do I have to use a CD or something? My objective is to get rid of Ubuntu 10.10 and use all 64GB on a higher version of Ubuntu. I have other laptops that are Lubuntu 15.04 and I can get things to work on those. What should I do?

UPDATE: I AM NOW DECIDING THAT I AM GOING TO GET A USB FLASH DRIVE AND DOWNLOAD UBUNTU TO IT. I FOUND A VIDEO ON YOUTUBE THAT SHOWS ME HOW TO DO IT. I UNDERSTAND IT. I AM GOING TO GET UBUNTU 14.04(WHATEVER THE NEWEST LTS IS) AND PUT OR ON MY PC. I WILL AT IT UP SO THE NEW UBUNTU WILL TOTALLY WIPE OUT THE OLD UBUNTU, SO THE NEW OS TAKES UP ALL THE HARD DRIVE SPACE.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 Has been EOL for years. I think the best option is to download the LTS, version 14.04, and install it via CD/DVD. Upgrading via this one, is not gonna work.

Comment: Follow the steps in that guide ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your data and see [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) for how to install a new version.

As 15.10 will be released tomorrow I'd rather install that (supported until July 2016) or 14.04LTS (supported until April 2019) then 15.04 (supported until January 2016).

Comment: Which one then? 15.10 or 14.04?